# Thai Language Not displaying Correctly on Iphone

Tags: ios

I have one thai language string
[image] .

but its showing as ‘บ้านต๊ำ’ on my UITextField in iOs Device / simulator

Comment: it is up to the current font-set, you need to choose (probably) set which supports / contains all characters for the desired language's alphabet.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried a font named Mitter-Regular, which solved my issue. Thanks.
Please write your comment as answer, i will accept it. @holex

Comment: I just did, I also mentioned in the foot-note that you have found a working font as a solution, I can't take credit for that, but it may be more useful to keep it in the answer rather than in the comment section in my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is a most likely a font-set issue here.

generally the issue is caused by not every font-set contains / supports all characters for the desired language's alphabet.

I'd recommend to try different font but I can't recommend any for Thai language, that is out of my language-skills.

---

***NOTE:*** As you mentioned in your comment the font called `Mitter-Regular` supports Thai alphabet for you correctly, I don't want to take credit for that information but I'd feel important to leave it in this answer too, because that may be useful for someone, who has the same issue as you did.